# In Java, the expression "+ + + + + +" is executed, the compiler reports no errors and can execute correctly？

Tags: java

I was writing this code in eclipse, it war written, and the result is `3d`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 5d + + + + + +-+3d;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: "*and the result is 3d.*" - Nope. The result is `2d`.

Comment: `+ + + + + +` is not an expression. It is a sequence of operators. Unary operators.

Answer (score 6):

Your expression can be rewritten as

```
(5d) + (+ + + + +-+3d)
```

Where the first `+` is the addition operator applied to two operands.

All the `+` and `-` in `+ + + + +-+3d` are unary operators that add up to the sign of the number `3d`.

In the end, your arithmetic expression is

```
5d + (-3d)
```

Which returns `2d`. You can apply multiple unary operators to an expression, as in the following examples:

```
+ - - 2 // 2
- + + 2 // -2
```

Answer (score 4):

The output of that code is `2.0`, and that is because all but the first `+` are **unary plus/minus operators**.

`+3d` is same as `3d`
`-+3d` is then same as `-3d`
`+-+3d` is then same as `-3d`
...
`+ + + + +-+3d` is then same as `-3d`
`5d + + + + + +-+3d` is then same as `5d + -3d`
Which is same as `5d - 3d`
So result is `2d`
Which prints as `2.0`